# Java Servlet and getRequestDispatcher not forwarding

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, forward

I'm working on a simple java web app that displays a page in which you can add a new client and then it shows another pages that presents the client newly added but i keep getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /LearningJSP/AddClient
type Status report
message /LearningJSP/AddClient
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I don't get where the problem is.
Here are the files of my app.

the "add new client" .jsp

```html
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Création d'un client</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="get" action="AddClient">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Informations client</legend>

                    <label for="nomClient">Nom <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="nomClient" name="nomClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="prenomClient">Prénom </label>
                    <input type="text" id="prenomClient" name="prenomClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="adresseClient">Adresse de livraison <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="adresseClient" name="adresseClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="telephoneClient">Numéro de téléphone <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="telephoneClient" name="telephoneClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="emailClient">Adresse email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailClient" name="emailClient" value="" size="20" maxlength="60" />
                    <br />
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" value="Valider"  />
                <input type="reset" value="Remettre à zéro" /> <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```java
package Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Model.Client;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ClientServ
 */

public class ClientServ extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String Add = "/affichierClient.jsp";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String Nom = request.getParameter("nomClient");
        String Prenom = request.getParameter("prenomClient");
        String Adresse = request.getParameter("adresseClient");
        String Telephone = request.getParameter("telephoneClient");
        String Email = request.getParameter("emailClient");

        String message;

        if(Nom.trim().isEmpty() ||  Adresse.trim().isEmpty() ||
                Telephone.trim().isEmpty()) {

            message="Vous n'avez pas rempli tous les champs"; 
            }

        else {
            message="Client crée avec succès"; 
            }

        Client client = new Client();
        client.setNom(Nom);
        client.setPrenom(Prenom);
        client.setAdresse(Adresse);
        client.setEmail(Email);
        client.setTelephone(Telephone);

        request.setAttribute("client", client);
        request.setAttribute("message", message);

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(Add).forward(request, response);      
    }


}
```

The jsp page to display the newly added client

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Affichage de client</title>
</head>
<body>

<p class="info"> ${message} </p>

<p>Nom: ${client.Nom}</p>
<p>Prenom: ${client.Prenom}</p>
<p>Adresse: ${client.Adresse}</p>
<p>Numéro de télephone: ${client.Telephone}</p>
<p>Email: ${client.Email}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>WebApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AddClient</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controllers.ClientServ</servlet-class>
    </servlet>



     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AddClient</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AddClient</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Is your JSP really named "affichierClient.jsp", with the typo? Is your servlet being called? Side note: you should not use GET to create a new client. That's what POST is for. And please, please, learn and respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Can you debug the servlet hit a breakpoint?. If you can that means the 404 is thrown on a subsequent request

Comment: @JBNizet The JSP file is named correctly and about the GET method, i was just following a tutorial on Openclassrooms and i did the exact same thing as they did, how can I use doPost instead?

Comment: @efekctive I'm sorry but I'm still a beginner can you please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the problem comes from that line:

```
<form method="get" action="AddClient">
```

As you give a relative URL instead of an absolute one, it is used to build a full URL **starting from the current one**.

So if the previous URL was `/LearningJSP` the following request  is sent to `/LearningJSP/AddClient` when it should use `/AddClient` ending in a normal 404 error.

Fix: just use an absolute URL:

```
<form method="get" action="/AddClient">
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about how to create breakpoints in eclipse.

Place a breakpoint here

```
String Nom = request.getParameter("nomClient");
```

Read about how to start a debugging session in eclipse.

Start one. If The execution never stops at the breakpoint means the configuration is wrong. If it does stop, means that the 404 is thrown in a subsequent request.

If you only have doGet(...) handling requests then you probably have url path issues